# Saving variables after a form is closed in WinForms with C++

Tags: c++, winforms

I am making an application in Windows Form in C++/cli language. I know it is not recommended but I begin it that way.

In that application I have 1 parent Form and 3 child Forms. In these child Forms the user can input some settings that are used in the parent Form. Those child Forms open when a user clicks on certain menu items on parent Form.
What I want is to save some of the variables (the settings) from the child forms after I close them (but not close the entire application). So when I open the child forms, the next time, these values are already set and I don’t have to re-set them again.

I have read about the settings at the application properties but as far as I know that works only in c#. The only way I found that works with C++, is to save these variables in a file, which is not practical in my application since when I close the whole application I want everything erased.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use the registry to store your settings to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Comment: why don't you expose them as properties and read them in the main form that spawned them? I'm guessing those forms are not modal, maybe you could handle [`FormClosed'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event